# Achieve good paging using objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I'm using objectify cursors to achieve basic paging, basically creating a `more` button..  How best do you achieve paging using objectify for building links that allow users to go forward and backwards.  Something more like a page list..

`1, 2, 3, 4, more`

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is probably to fetch the keys for the entire result set and stash it in a session or in javascript. Each next/previous can load the next item in your list by id. Loading by id is very cheap. You can cache the full query results in memcache as long as it's not too large but that's going to depend on what kind of objects you're fetching.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cursors to create paging by one page forward and backwards, via [`FetchOptions.startCursor(..)`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/FetchOptions.html#startCursor%28com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Cursor%29) and [`FetchOptions.endCursor(..)`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/FetchOptions.html#endCursor%28com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Cursor%29)

To create more direct paging links you will have to use [`FetchOptions.limit(..)`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/FetchOptions.html#limit%28int%29) and [`FetchOptions.offset(..)`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/FetchOptions.html#offset%28int%29).

Note that `offset(..)` can be very costly as it fetches all entities that come before given page. So, depending on usage and size of the whole set, you might be better off by preloading and caching a set of keys. Or better, replace paging with search.

Comment: Objectify is a pretty thin layer around low-level API - it actually uses low-level API's Cursor: http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Cursors

Comment: Yes, but that's not the syntax you use to access the cursors in objectify, and for pagination on a website I wouldn't use a cursor at all. I'd load the keys into a list and stick them into a session or in javascript onto the page.

Comment: .. and this is what actually my last paragraph says: `So, depending on usage and size of the whole set, you might be better off by preloading and caching a set of keys`